# How to empty list of list element one after another?

Tags: python, list

SO i have this working code but the problem is, its not working the way i like it.
Anyone have idea on this?

```
import time
numlist1 =[[1],[2],[3]]

def listdecrement():
    minVal=numlist1.index(min(numlist1)) # getting minimum value by index position
    minVal_add = minVal+1
    if minVal < minVal_add:
        numlist1[minVal].clear() # deleting value in index with minimum value
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print("updating")
        print(numlist1)

while True:
    listdecrement()
```

output :

```
[[], [2], [3]]
updating
[[], [2], [3]]
updating
[[], [2], [3]]
```

desired output :

```
[[], [2], [3]]
updating
[[], [], [3]]
updating
[[], [], []]
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? One example isn't really enough to go off of.

Comment: Your `min` isn't doing what you think its doing, its always returning the first list. (I don't know what you're trying to achieve with this min though)

Comment: `min(numlist1)` compares the inner lists lexicographically. Therefore an empty list (if present) is minimum. The min function has a "key" parameter which you could fill with an appropriate lambda or function to look for a value in the inner list.

Comment: I think you mean *your code isn't working*. By definition, working code is code that does what you want it to do. The question is, *what do you want the code to do exactly*? Thank you for providing example outputs, but adding a description always helps.

Comment: You can delete the desired item in a list like so `numlist1.remove(numlist1[minVal])`

Comment: Whereas `min([[2],[1],[3]])` returns `[1]`, `min([[],[2],[3]])` returns `[]`.

Comment: the deleted element  in index will always be interpreted as minimum value, thats why will always return in index 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `min` function over list containing empty list, it returns the empty list as the index , because `min` is actually `0`, which is the minimal element though, and therefore you attempt to change the same index all the time, to make it clear look at this:

```
list_to_check = [[],[2],[3]]
min_index =list_to_check.index(min(list_to_check))
print(min_index)

# returns 0
```

to fix it, you have to check the `min` over the legal elements (which means not empty ones) as in this modified solution:

```
import time
numlist1 =[[1],[2],[3]]

def listdecrement():
    if (len([item for item in numlist1 if len(item)])>0):
        minVal=numlist1.index(min(item for item in numlist1 if len(item)>0)) # getting minimum value by index position
    else:
        return
    minVal_add = minVal+1
    if minVal < minVal_add:
        numlist1[minVal].clear() # deleting value in index with minimum value
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print("updating")
        print(numlist1)

while True:
    listdecrement()
```

output:

```
updating
[[], [2], [3]]
updating
[[], [], [3]]
updating
[[], [], []]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may first flatten list `[[],[2],[3]]` into `[2, 3]` and then find the minimum value `2` which is then being searched as a list `[2]`:

```
import time
numlist1 =[[1],[2],[3]]

def listdecrement():
    flat_list = [item for sublist in numlist1 for item in sublist]
    minVal=numlist1.index([min(flat_list)]) # getting minimum value by index position
    minVal_add = minVal+1
    if minVal < minVal_add:
        numlist1[minVal].clear() # deleting value in index with minimum value
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print("updating")
        print(numlist1)

while True:
    try:
        listdecrement()
    except ValueError:
        break
```

which outputs

```
updating
[[], [2], [3]]
updating
[[], [], [3]]
updating
[[], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixes

1. Since each item is a one element array, give min a key so it can handle []
2. Check if all items in list is empty to prevent infinite loop

**Code**

```
import time
import sys
numlist1 =[[1],[2],[3]]

def listdecrement():
    # add key to min so we compare item in list i.e. for
    # for [2] => key function returns 2, 
    # for [] => key function return sys.maxsize (max integer)
    minVal=numlist1.index(min(numlist1, key = lambda v: v[0] if v else sys.maxsize)) # getting minimum value by index position
    minVal_add = minVal+1
    if minVal < minVal_add:
        numlist1[minVal].clear() # deleting value in index with minimum value
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print("updating")
        print(numlist1)

while any(x for x in numlist1): # True if any elements 
                                # are not [] in numlist1
    listdecrement()
```

**Output**

```
updating
[[], [2], [3]]
updating
[[], [], [3]]
updating
[[], [], []]
```